# Change color of a link when parent div is hovered in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind and trying to change the color of `<a>` link when the parent `<div>` is hovered. I know usually `hover` is used on the element itself, but in this case I am aiming to only change the color when the parent div is hovered.

code:

`

Text

Link
`

Answer (score 1):

In tailwind 3 there is the "group modifier" for styling based on a parent state:

```
<div class="group">
    <p>some text that does not change color</p>
    <a href="#" class="group-hover:text-red">some text that changes color</a>
</div>
```

"group" is the keyword tailwind is using.

See also: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state